# Method to compress data by eliminating meaningless bit

Tags: python, c, dataframe, compression

I am dealing with time-series data.

At each sample timing, i get a sample and the size of this value is not full-byte.

for example, if sample is data of 7 bits, it uses only 7 bits on a byte.

first sample = 0b 0100 1000,
second sample = 0b 0110 0010
and so on…

originally,
0100 1000 0110 0010

but i want to get
10 0100 0110 0010

how can i apply this compressing method to both encode and decode??

is there any official compressing theory using this method?

Comment: You could compress the data in the way you suggest but you'd never be able to decompress it thus making the exercise pointless

Comment: @Fredrik Sure if all the data are 7-bit but the question implies that the significant values may be fewer than 7 bits. I quote "...not full byte..."

Comment: there are some datas as data1, data2, data3… but if i choose one data, that has fixed bit size. for example data1 is 7bit, data2 is 5bit. for data1 i get 7bit samples by time

Answer (score 3):

Use bit operations to write seven bits at a time to a buffer of bits you maintain in two variables, writing out bytes as you accumulate them. In the end, you will still need to write out full bytes, so the last byte may have some unused bits. Decoding reads seven bits at a time from the bitstream, using the same approach.

Encode (in C):

```
unsigned buf = 0, bits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sample_count; i++) {
    buf |= sample[i] << bits;
    bits += 7;
    if (bits >= 8) {
        putchar(buf & 0xff);
        buf >>= 8;
        bits -= 8;
    }
}
if (bits > 0)
    putchar(buf);
```

Decode (glossing over how you know how big to make sample[]):

```
unsigned buf = 0, bits = 0, n = 0;
for (;;) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF)
        break;
    buf |= ch << bits;
    bits += 8;
    do {
        sample[n++] = buf & 0x7f;
        buf >>= 7;
        bits -= 7;
    } while (bits >= 7);
}
```

Comment: I love it that this relatively simple question about little-c compression got a very nice answer from one of the deans of big-C compression! :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit I really agree!!