# How to compress a text file using the concept that ASCII is only 0-127 ==> the MSB (last digit in binary) is always zero in C

Tags: c, while-loop, compression, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to compress a text file using the concept that ASCII is only 0-127
==> the MSB (last digit in binary) is always zero. I want to convert that zero to be the LSB of the next binary number of the next char.

The method convert8to7 is working fine from offset 10-17 and after that it's not.

```
***main***

int main() {

    printf("enter name of input file (.bin at the end): ");
    char* input=NULL;
    char* output8to7=NULL;
    size_t bufsize=0;
    size_t bufsize2=0;
    getline(&input,&bufsize,stdin);
    if(input==NULL)
    { printf("getline didnt worked well");}
    printf("enter name of output file (.bin at the end): ");
    getline(&output8to7,&bufsize2,stdin);
    if(output8to7==NULL)
    { printf("getline didnt worked well");}
    int lastindex =strlen(input);
    input[lastindex-1]='\0'; //because the stdin ad \n in the end of the char*
    FILE* inputfile=fopen(input, "r");
    if(inputfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("couldnt open input file ");
        printf(input);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int lastindex2= strlen(output8to7);
    output8to7[lastindex2-1]='\0'; //because the stdin ad \n in the end of the char*
    FILE* file8to7=fopen(output8to7, "wb");
    if(file8to7==NULL)
    {
        printf("couldnt open output file");
        printf(output8to7);
        exit(-1);
    }
    compress8to7(inputfile,file8to7);
    fclose(file8to7);
    fclose(inputfile);
    return 0;
}

***method***


void compress8to7(FILE *input,FILE* output8to7)
{
    // 0x00 87 00 87 00 87 00 87 ll
    uint64_t magic=0x87008700870087ll;
    uint64_t outputsize=(sizeof(input)*0.875)+sizeof(magic);
    outputsize=outputsize+sizeof (outputsize);
    fwrite(&magic,sizeof (magic),1,output8to7);
    fwrite(&outputsize,sizeof(outputsize),1,output8to7);
    unsigned  char st;
    unsigned char st2;
    char shift=7;
    char shift_st=0;
    char bdigit=1; //help for calculate binary numbers
    unsigned char inbfile; // will contain the resullt of the asked new  binary lines comprees
    int breakflag=0;
    int breakflag2=0;
    int cnt=0;//this parameter will help to know when we dont need to move 1 back in the pointer of input file
    while(1) {
        cnt++;
        if (ftell(input)>1 && cnt%9!=0) //i think need to be change to cnt%8
        {
            fseek(input,-1 ,SEEK_CUR) ;
        }
        if ((st = fgetc(input)) == EOF) { breakflag=1;break; }
        st2 = fgetc(input);
        if(st2==EOF){breakflag2=1;break;} //need to do something when st2==EOF

        st2=st2<<shift; //move the digit to the right position
        st=st>>shift_st;

        st=st<<shift_st;//this operation for reset the last beats to zero
        st=st>>shift_st; //this operation for reset the last beats to zero

        shift_st++;
        if(shift_st==8)
            {shift_st=0;}

        inbfile=st2|st;
        fwrite(&inbfile,sizeof (inbfile),1,output8to7);
        shift=shift-1;
        if(shift==-1)
            shift=7;
if(feof(input))
            {break;}

    }
```

***this what i get, in line 2 (offset 10-17) its work fine and after it is not***

[image]

***this is how its should be***

[image]

***the txt file i working on contain the next line:***

"A hex dump is a hexadecimal view of computer data, from memory or from a computer file."

***and this is his hexdump***
[image]

Comment: i am using now the function feof() ,and the while does stop and work fine. but still just from offset 10-17 its work and after its isnt

Comment: `((st = fgetc(input)) == EOF)` Function `fgetc` returns a `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of photos of your text. Instead copy&paste text directly into the question as formatted text.

Comment: `uint64_t outputsize=(sizeof(input)*0.875)+sizeof(magic);` This is wrong in many ways. 1) `input` is a pointer. It's size is not at all related to the size of the area where it points to. 2) You must round up to multiple of 7 bytes. 3) `sizeof` yields a `size_t`. No need to use 64 bit data type in case `size_t` is only 32 bits

Comment: Besides this, you should start using a debugger. If your function only works for the very first set of 8 bytes, you should step through your code and see what happens afterwards. What instructions are executed, what values do your variables hold then? Is that what you expected before?

Comment: Saar Weinberg, Rather than a hexdump as a pic, post as text.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the OP for [Compressing from 8-bit to 7 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72448076/15168)?  It seems like the same exercise, but it's not one I recall seeing on SO before.

Comment: `if ((st = fgetc(input)) == EOF)` is _never_ true.  Use `int st;`.

Comment: You might see this question: [Method to compress data by eliminating meaningless bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72302611).